# Drawing translucent shapes without overlapping

Tags: android, drawing

I am drawing several circles with transparency. The number of circles and their positions are not fixed. Currently I am setting the transparent color in a `Paint` object and drawing the circles in a for loop with the `Canvas` object. But that causes overlapping.

I have thought of a method:
- Render all the circles as opaque on something other than the main canvas.
- Set the transparency.
- Draw the final object on canvas.

How do i implement that on android?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If the circles shouldn't overlap, draw them further apart.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new bitmap with ARGB888, and draw on it's canvas all your shapes with no transparency.
Then draw the new bitmap into the main canvas using a Paint on which you called setAlpha earlier