# how to resolve overlapping on draw of multiple path

Tags: android, drawing, overlapping

i want to draw multiple path with multiple paint stroke width on the canvas, but overlapping problem occurs on collision of path.

[color overlapping when drawing multiple path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522496/color-overlapping-when-drawing-multiple-path/16522713?noredirect=1#comment23754171_16522713)

Above link contains explanation. Overlapping occurs when i set alpha to paint. But this is requirement of application. If other way to make paint semi-transparent with using alpha.
Please suggest.
Thanks

Comment: You'd have to remove the alpha from the paint to fix this overlapping issue you're having, but that is not what you want. Your problem looks similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10944811/1449972), so you might take a look at that answer.

Comment: tried but does nothing. i am unable to find solution but image editing apps like after focus etc does. if i make only one object of path then overlapping resolve but in this situation i am unable to provide paint stroke width for multiple contour of path. Any Suggestion..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it'll help you

```
mPaint.setARGB(90, 255, 0, 0);
mPaint.setXfermode(new AvoidXfermode(Color.RED, 90, Mode.AVOID));
```

if you are drawing on canvas than you need to set transparent bitmap to canvas otherwise AvoidXfermode will detect rgb of image.